# Strange character while reading a CSV file

Tags: python, encoding

I try to read a CSV file in Python, but the first element in the first row is read like that `ï»¿0`, while the strange character isn't in the file, its just a simple `0`. Here is the code I used:

```
matriceDist=[]
file=csv.reader(open("distanceComm.csv","r"),delimiter=";")
for row in file:
    matriceDist.append(row)
print (matriceDist)
```

Comment: These characters form the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of the file. Use `encoding` to open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use pandas together with some encoding (utf-8 for example) is gonna be easier

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('distanceComm.csv', header=None, encoding = 'utf8', delimiter=';')
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks it worked , but i think it read the first row as headers of columns , i'll have to add something in the code or adding a row in my file

Comment: I think I should read more about pandas it seems easier to use .. thank you for the help

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue.  Save your excel file as CSV (MS-DOS) vs. UTF-8 and those odd characters should be gone.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer answers the OP's question best

Answer (score 8):

Specifying the byte order mark when opening the file as follows solved my issue:

`open('inputfilename.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your input file is. But since it has a [Byte Order Mark for UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), you can use something like this:

```
import codecs
matriceDist=[]
file=csv.reader(codecs.open('distanceComm.csv', encoding='utf-8'),delimiter=";")
for row in file:
    matriceDist.append(row)
print (matriceDist)
```

Comment: I still got this : '\ufeff0'  instead of   '0'

Comment: What is your exact input file? It might also help to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark as suggested by Lutz Horn

Comment: my input file was originally an excel file , I saved it in a csv format and it only has numbers like that: 0;23;45;8;4... in each row.. I'll read the article You suggested thank you